# Circular refrence in struct

Tags: rust

I have a struct `A` as a container,

```rust
struct A {
   children: Vec<T>,
   // other fields
},
```

a trait `T`,

```rust
trait T {
    // some methods
}
```

and several implementations of `T`: `B`, `C`, etc.

```rust
struct B(_ref_to_A_);
impl T for B {}
```

I want that, `B` hold a reference to `A` while `A` have `B` in its `children`. So how can I change the definition of `A` and `B` to achieve my goal.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have read that post before asking this question. It told me why rather than how, and I wonder if there is really not any solution, such as `Rc`, `Pin` (I have only a little knowledge of these techniques).

Comment: See the "How to fix it" section.